# How to remove .php and .html extension in nginx, but make the .php show 404

Tags: nginx

So how to remove the .php and .html extension in nginx?

For example:
https://example.com/example.php should redirect to https://example.com/example

https://example.com/example1.html should redirect to https://example.com/example1

And also how do i make example.php to be a 404, but example to show example.php?

Comment: You should search for extensionless php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used extensionless php and it now works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).